# Changing the format specifier in the printf() method results in IllegalFormatFlagsException

Tags: java, methods, format, printf

In the following code, after changing the format specifier in the `printf()` method from `%04d%n` to `%0-4d%n`, and running the code results in

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatFlagsException:
>
> Flags = '-0'

The complete source code is as follows:

```
public class MinArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        byte[] storeMinimum = new byte[5];
        byte[] trialArray = new byte[15];

        for(byte bt=0; bt < storeMinimum.length; bt++){
            randomize(trialArray);
            storeMinimum[bt] = findMinimum(trialArray);
        }

        for (byte minValue : storeMinimum)
            System.out.printf("%0-4d%n", minValue);

    }

    private static byte findMinimum(byte[] valArray) {
        byte minValue = valArray[0];

        for(byte bt=0; bt < valArray.length; bt++)
            minValue = (byte) Math.min(minValue, valArray[bt]);

        return minValue;
    }

    private static void randomize(byte[] valArray) {
        for (byte bt = 0; bt < valArray.length; bt++)
            valArray[bt] = (byte) (Math.random()*128);
    }

}
```

Can someone explain, how this could have happened, since I wanted the byte literal to be displayed as left-justified with 4 character positions? Also, please do suggest a fix for the same.

Comment: I suggest you have a look into this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650126/formatting-dice-roll-output-java/39650674#39650674

Comment: I figured out that, '0' and '-' can not be used together in the printf() method format specifier. Although, I must admit that I couldn't find it explicitly stated anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think when you write

```
System.out.printf("%04d%n", minValue);
```

It's right-justified. All the empty space in left will replaced by '0'.

The '-' is used for left-justified.

They can't be used together.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are searching for:

```
System.out.printf("%-4d%n", minValue);
```

Also:

> **Integer** formatting

```
%d   : will print the integer as it is.
%6d  : will print the integer as it is. If the number of digits is less than 6, the output will be padded on the left.
%-6d : will print the integer as it is. If the number of digits is less than 6, the output will be padded on the right.
%06d : will print the integer as it is. If the number of digits is less than 6, the output will be padded on the left with zeroes.
%.2d : will print maximum 2 digits of the integer.
```

> **String** formatting

```
%s    : will print the string as it is.
%15s  : will print the string as it is. If the string has less than 15 characters, the output will be padded on the left.
%-6s  : will print the string as it is. If the string has less than 6 characters, the output will be padded on the right.
%.8d  : will print maximum 8 characters of the string.
```

> **Floating** point formatting

```
%f    : will print the number as it is.
%15f  : will print the number as it is. If the number has less than 15 digits, the output will be padded on the left.
%.8f  : will print maximum 8 decimal digits of the number.
%9.4f : will print maximum 4 decimal digits of the number. The output will occupy 9 characters at least. If the number of digits is not enough, it will be padded
```